# Need to increase the allowable maximum height for a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, virtualization, virtualscroll

Is this possible to increase the below maximum allowable height to be set to a div element.

Chrome (14.0) :    33,554,428 px

IE (9.0)      :     10,737,418 px

FF (7.0.1)    :     17,895,697 px

Beyond, the size, the client height of the div element won't be increased. It creates a problem in virtual scrolling in grid. Beyond the limit, the grid won't be scroll.

Any one having solution for that?

Comment: Doubt it's possible, probably better to restructure your code to not exceed that height.

Comment: You meant to say that your page is longer than 10 million pixel?

Comment: If you infinite scroll such height, won't you end up having a memory problem with all the things you'll have loaded? It feels more like a design smell to go over those limits. You'd probably want to rethink your design.

Comment: In grid, i am having 1 million rows, each cells in row having 40px of height. The height shouldn't be changed. I can only scroll 90% of rows.